# .NET facebook sdk silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

im trying to develop a silverlight application that uses facebook sdk, after some research i found an example [here (source code and samples)](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/66412).
i studied the CSSilverlightInBrowser project and i understand how it works a little, but when i try to run the project i get this error in the facebook window **"An error occurred with ----. Please try again later"**. I already replaced the application id and the app secret  in the application.
i would really appreciate any help, thanks.

edit : after a couple of tries i figured out that when i call FacebookOAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(...) if i give null instead of this redirect url @"http://localhost:18201/slfbinbrowserlogin.aspx" i get a blank page that says "Success", so i believe this where it goes wrong(redirect url), (i thaught maybe facebook would'nt find the redirect url i gave since it's on my local machine so i tried google.com and it still did not work)
please any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I received this problem numerous times trying to get the SDK to work, and then a few issues porting a working sample into my own project.  Things that caused this included:

this parameter must be included when loading your .xap

```
- <param name='enableHtmlAccess' value='true' />
```

make sure you also include a reference to the javascript method your SL will call

```
- <param name="onLoad" value="slLoaded" />
```

also ensure you have the `div id="silverlightFacebook"` set (or whatever name the SDK javascript calls)

make sure "Site URL" is set in the web section on facebook development app console - https://developers.facebook.com/apps

make sure the *excellent* caching browsers seem to do with silverlight isn't tripping you up.. you might be loading an old version ;)

if you are using anonymous methods you might be getting an internal JSON error in the library which is being handled siliently. see http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/265941 I had to add the following to assemblyinfo.cs 
    [assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Facebook")]

At the time of writing, the 'stable' version (5.0.50.0) of the facebook SDK on codeplex has some bugs which prevent posting from working, however I **can** successfully post by downloading the *latest* changeset and building the source with my project.  the sdk source code builds nicely and is organized well so easy to attach to your own project.